# WebCrawl exercise done using sync.WaitGroup panics. What I am doing wrong? What would be Go idiomatic solution?

Tags: go

I am learning Go using their "A Tour of Go". I managed to do all exercises but the last one has me frustrated. It is dying with `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

var urlCache = make(map[string]bool)
var mutex = sync.Mutex{}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    fmt.Printf("Crawl: %v \n", url)

    if depth <= 0 {
        fmt.Println("Crawl: reached depth")
        return
    }

    mutex.Lock()
    if alreadyFetched := urlCache[url]; alreadyFetched {
        fmt.Printf("Crawl: %v already fetched\n", url)
        return
    }
    urlCache[url] = true
    mutex.Unlock()

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Crawl: found %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, wg)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    fmt.Println("Main: Starting worker")
    wg.Add(1)
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, &wg)
    fmt.Println("Main: Waiting for workers to finish")

    fmt.Println("Main: Completed")

    wg.Wait()
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Any tips and help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit1: In-lined code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
    mutex.Lock()
    if alreadyFetched := urlCache[url]; alreadyFetched {
        fmt.Printf("Crawl: %v already fetched\n", url)
        return
    }
    urlCache[url] = true
    mutex.Unlock()
```

When the `if` condition is true, you return without unlocking the shared mutex.

So eventually the other goroutines will deadlock on `mutex.Lock()`, because the goroutine which acquired it never released.

Call `mutex.Unlock()` also in the `if` block before returning.

You could also use `defer mutex.Unlock()` right after locking, and before the `if` statement, and in a trivial application this won't make an appreciable difference, but in a real-world scenario you want to keep the resource locked for the shortest time possible. If you have a function body with other long-running operations, unlocking immediately after the `if` is acceptable. But then you must remember to release the lock if the `if` can return control flow to the caller.